# Time to groupBy and sum spark DF rise proportionally to number of sums?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
df.groupBy("c1").agg(sum("n1")).distinct.count()
```

would take 10 seconds

```
df.groupBy("c1").agg(sum("n1"), sum("n2")).distinct.count()
```

would take 20 seconds

It suprises me since row storage of DFs. Do you have same experience & how does this make sense? Also ideas how to make 2 sums run in more similar time to 1 sum? spark 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "agg" takes two much more time in second case. I would look towards distinct.

You're executing *distinct* based on extra column *n2*, which gives broader distribution and increase complexity of distinct calulation.

Comment: no - group by c1 makes the DF really small, hundreds of rows. From billions.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense:

- You increase number of computations twofold.
- You increase shuffle size roughly 50%.

Both changes will impact overall performance, even if final result is small and impact on distinct is negligible.